# How to set ToolTip's max width

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tooltip

I have a ToolTip which I want to assign maximum width to, and whenever the ToolTip reaches that width, it just jump a row down, just like label does.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

That capability is not exposed in Winforms.  A workaround is to insert line-breaks in the string to get multi-line tips.  For example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me, "Hello" + vbCrLf + "world")
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: I have thought about this solution but the problem is, my text is being extracted from a database. I have found a solution to my problem by using some routine. Post the routine here?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to, you can set `OwnerDraw` = true and handle the Draw event yourself. An example can be found on this [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw.aspx).